# strange encoding characters on php form

Tags: php, encoding

I'm trying to learn PHP forms, inputting data, outputting results on a basic html form page with a button. However, it doesn't send me to the right PHP link, and instead shows a broken 404 not found link, and it seems to be that I'm having some weird encoding issues on apache.

I even uploaded this to my hosting, and I get further strange encoding for the link which is simply supposed to be named `handle_calc.php`

> The requested URL /Ã¢â‚¬Å“handle_calc.phpÃ¢â‚¬Â was not found on this server.

Any tips on, what needs to be changed? I'm amazed that both environments won't show a basic form php correctly by default.

html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=“en”>
<head>
<meta charset=“utf-8”>
<title>Product Cost Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>

<div><p>Fill out this form to calculate the total cost:</p>

<form action=“handle_calc.php” method=“post”>

<p>Price: <input type=“text” name=“price” size=“5”></p>

<p>Quantity: <input type="number" name=“quantity” size=“5” min=“1” 
value=“1”></p>

<p>Discount: <input type=“text” name=“discount” size=“5”></p>

<p>Tax: <input type=“text” name=“tax” size=“5”> (%)</p>

<p>Shipping method: <select name=“shipping”>
<option value=“5.00”>Slow and steady</option>
<option value=“8.95”>Put a move on it.</option>
<option value=“19.36”>I need it yesterday!</option>
</select></p>

<p>Number of payments to make: <input type="number" name="payments" size=“5” 
min=“1” value=“1”></p>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate!">

</form>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

php:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang=“en”>
<head>
 <meta charset=“utf-8”>
<title>Product Cost Calculator</title>

<style type=“text/css”>
 .number { font-weight: bold; }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<?php

//get the values from the $_POST array

$price = $_POST[‘price’];
$quantity = $_POST[‘quantity’];
$discount = $_POST[‘discount’];
$tax = $_POST[‘tax’];
$shipping = $_POST[‘shipping’];
$payments = $_POST[‘payments’];

//calculate the total:

$total = $price * $quantity;
$total = $total + $shipping;
$total = $total - $discount;

//determine tax rate

$taxrate = $tax / 100;
$taxrate = $taxrate + 1;

//factor in the tax rate:
$total = $total * $taxrate;

//calculate the monthly payments
$monthly = $total / $payments

//print out results

print “<p>You have selected to purchase:<br>
<span class=\”number\”>$quantity</span> widget(s) at <br>
$<span class=\”number\”>$price</span>price each plus a <br>
$<span class=\”number\”>$shipping</span>shipping cost and a <br>
<span class=\”number\”>$tax</span>percent tax rate.<br>
After your $<span class=\”number\”>$discount</span>discount, the total cost 
is $<span class=\”number\”>$total</span>.<br>
Divided over <span class=\”number\”>$payments</span>monthly payments, that 
would be $<span class=\”number\”>$monthly</span> each.</p>”;

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: at least show the form code

Comment: sure. figured it wasn't the coding that was the issue. ill revise now

Comment: since its live(?) a url to see it would be great to

Comment: http://scr4mblr.com/calculator.html

Comment: those are NOT regular quote marks you have. what are you coding in? but fixing the quotes should solve this

Comment: Hm, so weird my text editor isn't even showing a difference barely. I have no idea how that's happening. I think i need a new text editor lol. thanks

Comment: apart from word i know no editor that will use “ for " without you changing the settings

Comment: I actually think it had to do with copy and pasting the code a few different times over different environments. that's my guess anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your form action attribute is using special characters rather than standard double quotes. You appear to be using special characters throughout. Replace all occurrences of those special chars with regular double / single quotes.

Comment: Hm, so weird my text editor isn't even showing a difference barely. I have no idea how that's happening. I think i need a new text editor lol. thanks

Comment: @Wilson - Try notepad++, Personally I use Eclipse PDT